# react testing library - test window.addEventListener('resize')

Tags: jestjs, window, addeventlistener, react-testing-library

I am using jest & react-testing-library.
In my component on didMount I add an event listener to the window reacting on resize events. Based on resize events, another function is called. In my test, that function is mocked.

Now I have the problem, that I am not able to trigger these resize events.
Is there any way to get that done?

```
   window.resizeTo(500, 500);
   fireEvent.resize(window);
   fireEvent(window, new Event("resize"));
```

I tried to achieve the triggering of the event listener on different ways, but nothing worked.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: "_Based on resize events_": Is the conditional for invoking the mocked function actually being met by your dispatched synthetic resize event?

Comment: Well, if a resize happens a function is called that triggers some effects. In best case, I would test if these effects are triggered. Somehow I just failed to trigger that function that is bound to the event listener

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to spy on `window.addEventListener` to make sure that it's been invoked (and your mock function is registered) before you dispatch the resize event:

> The example component is a functional one and uses the effect hook, but the test should be the same for a class component.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjiwJQFE00VKBfONKCEOAcihlKfANwAoUJFiI0wQQwBuKAHbU4g5aig0A7hmAwAYtA5ce-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-B5+HxmCJ+2sgDqhAAghayQAVCDbkc6RGYIooVYAoHwaDARnKQoAWRQ-Ig5PaEeNOjNFrrpuyZQP6gLKMCBBgN4iJZDAJpQd4ADyyjDL+Cw0Hw5qWpOG52iBfBVi8iEmjG-QAJLgJCID1Bgdg7F8JpMV4DgEMivxqlyABCrDYPQcD8sK5B0DA5iSNRtH0UsQkBNY5JoNAAlihS0HspyWIAFKJMOpxwPM9I7A4rJwNgokgHRTLdDBCpKhKymPs+hQmpxWLkfAdRkkQoncgixp1HA5n1lZqrog59hvh+IJfsMTFmlArFEeq95wMWKC4Ue5QoOWiIsQQ-ovMAaAjGl9QZRUrQVfwaauoRJmrowuHAQ6u4EAeqBICeZ6Rhe7S0lgN6Fol4HAh2fSwYkJpoKhBYvBoWjDAAPNcOz1IgsXHN0mpsBwviTIlXK7gYnCKZKY7pgino5sZ9hKVKNQrYc3luAigiMkmgjksMdCMMwsSdJt5xykQM6bKMaIYHoR2Q0Y0BfOxcBRDEnwYPVQH4c1+6Hh1p7nqMJqiTxR5QLyILeGMM2cHIDX1Ca1XwmhuP+ojsTDKNeOiQAEhgSg8SolTdGS2r6hiWLQqJgi3XAYUvjgAWRV+AkQMO3UAThNro6yaIkWRfRi9AKBC2wBZAA)

`example.test.tsx`:

```ts
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {fireEvent, render, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';

type ComponentProps = { callback: () => unknown };

function Component ({callback}: ComponentProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      // You described some extra logic here,
      // but this is where the callback is invoked:
      callback();
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, [callback]);

  return null;
}

test('callback is invoked after window resize event', async () => {
  let aResizeEventListenerWasAddedToWindow = false;

  const originalMethod = window.addEventListener;
  const spy = jest.spyOn(window, 'addEventListener');

  spy.mockImplementation((...args) => {
    // Because this custom implementation is created for the spy,
    // Jest will no longer automatically invoke the original.
    // It needs to be done manually:
    originalMethod(...args);

    const [eventType] = args;
    if (eventType === 'resize') aResizeEventListenerWasAddedToWindow = true;
  });

  const callback = jest.fn();
  render(<Component {...{callback}} />);

  // Wait for the resize handler in the component to be registered (useEffect callback is async)
  await waitFor(() => expect(aResizeEventListenerWasAddedToWindow).toBeTruthy());
  fireEvent.resize(window);
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // Restore the original method to window.addEventListener
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, did not expect that someone would put such an effort on it. Just one more question. Is there an opportunity to call the real implementation of that mock function? Simulating a window resize, real event listener will get called and that bound function will be called?

Comment: @MaikHartmann Sure: just pass the real callback function to the component instead of the mock one. You can copy and paste the entire test and modify that one aspect in the second test if you want to keep both.

Comment: The problem is, that the function, that is invoked, is not passed to the component. It's part of the class component and bound to the event listener on mount. So I actually need to depend on using the original functionality of the resize event listener and need the real function to be called

Comment: The problem is, that the component does not react to the resize event. I bound a function with just a console.log to the event listener and it just does not get invoked