# How can we write test case for the agGrid onGridSizeChanged in React using React testing library and jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, ag-grid-react

I am currently using the onGridSizeChanged event from the ag-grid react.
It meets the functionality requirement in our application but unable to cover the method
in unit test cases.

I am currently using the onGridSizeChanged event from the ag-grid react.
It meets the functionality requirement in our application but unable to cover the method
in unit test cases.

for writing unit test cases currently using:
React testing library
Jest

Functionality wise the onGridSizeChanged method is being called on first render.
And the same is not happening with the unit test cases.

**Sample component code:**
`const onGridSizeChanged =useCallback((params)=>{
// our requirement
},[])
return (

```
 <div className='ag-theme-alpine'>
   <div calssName='gridStylings'>
     <AGGridReact
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columndef} 
      onGrdiRead={onGridReady}
      onGridSizeChanged={onGridSizeChanged}
    />

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

);

`
I tried to fire the resize event through the test cases.
Providing the samples used for the window resize event firing

Providing stackoverflow solution used for window resize
[react testing library - test window.addEventListener('resize')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987496/react-testing-library-test-window-addeventlistenerresize)

Can anyone help me to find out the solution/provide solution for the test case for onGridSizeChanged.

Thank you.